# Is it possible to query the join table using HQL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

My Database:

```
WorkflowProcess
id | name

WorkflowProcessToWorkflowProcess
ancestor | descendent
```

I need to query for root `WorkflowProcess`.  With this table structure, I'm looking to query something like `SELECT * FROM WorkflowProcess WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT descendent FROM WorkflowProcessToWorkflowProcess)`

My `WorkflowProcess` entity:

```
private Collection<WorkflowProcessEntity> workflowProcesses;

@JoinTable(name = "Workflow_Process_to_Workflow_Process", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ancestor", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "descendent", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany()
public Collection<WorkflowProcessEntity> getWorkflowProcesses() {
    return workflowProcesses;
}

public void setWorkflowProcesses(Collection<WorkflowProcessEntity> workflowProcesses) {
    this.workflowProcesses = workflowProcesses;
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select child 
from WorkflowProcess parent right join parent.workflowProcesses child 
where parent is null
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!